# Mapview Instancing vs Google Maps API quotas

Tags: android, google-maps, quota, gmsmapview, single-instance

I am creating my first app on Android and it uses com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView in at least 3 activities and fragments.
As such, I'm calling the following code in each activity onCreate to create a MapView:

```
MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
mMapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
if(mMapView != null){
   mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
```

Since i have learnt there are quotas on the google maps implementations and i plan to have some paid features on my app (although they don't really concern google maps so i don't use any Premium plan or whatever, i just have an API key), i was wondering :

1) Would it be possible to instantiate MapView only once at the start of my application and then use it as some sort of singleton and call it whenever needed in multiple activites ? (I'm asking because i have no idea how to do so, i would appreciate some tips or examples about it if it is in fact possible)

2) Can someone confirm that this i a problem i should be concerned with, regarding the fact that i don't have any premium plan and that i am using the most basic features of googlemaps (i.e : show map views and add markers on it)

Thank you for your time. 
Also this is my first post and i don't have much experience in android, i hope i'm being clear enough.